# Execute T-SQL scalar function with EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have created scalar function in SQL Server using SSMS 2016.

I want to execute this function from my ASP.NET Core 6 app.

I tried this but that doesn't work:

```
var Items = await Task.Run(() => administrationDbContext.OcrDictInfos
           .FromSqlRaw("  select Top(1) Id, Keyword, dbo.ProcessWords({0}) as Description from Info", myText));
var DataResult = Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result.Describtion;
return DataResult;
```

Comment: *"doesn't work"* isn't a helpful problem statement. *Explain* why it doesn't work.

Comment: Though I do note that `Describtion` <> `Description`.

Comment: any time you find yourself typing `.Result`: check whether you could have used `await` instead

Comment: Because it is relevant for answers: What _version_ of EF Core is in use here?

Comment: .Dotnet 6 Asp core .Net core 6

Comment: Fyi the version of ssms is irrelevant as it's just the UI. We need the version of SQL server e.g. `select @@version`

Comment: I used SSMS 2019

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use interpolated strings for parameters, then use `FromSqlInterpolated`.

```cs
var Items = administrationDbContext.OcrDictInfos
    .FromSqlInterpolated(@$"
select Top(1)
  Id,
  Keyword,
  dbo.ProcessWords({myText}) as Description
from Info;");

var DataResult = (await Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync()).Description;
return DataResult;
```

Otherwise use `FromSqlRaw`, but create an actual `Sqlparameter` object.

```cs
var Items = administrationDbContext.OcrDictInfos
    .FromSqlRaw(@"
select Top(1)
  Id,
  Keyword,
  dbo.ProcessWords(@myText) as Description
from Info;",
  new SqlParameter("@myText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100) { Value = myText}
);

var DataResult = (await Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync()).Description;
return DataResult;
```

Note also that your existing `await Task.Run` mess doesn't make any sense and should be removed. It probably doesn't do what you think it does, and will end up blocking because of the `.Result`.

---

Having said that, [you can use scalar functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) directly in normal EF Core queries.

First add a dummy function to your context

```cs
public string ProcessWords(string? Value) =>
    throw new NotSupportedException();
```

Then add it to your model

```cs
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(AdministrationDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(ProcessWords), new[] { typeof(string) }))
    .HasName("ProcessWords")
    .HasSchema("dbo");
```

Then you can just do

```cs
var Items =
    from i in administrationDbContext.OcrDictInfos
    select new OcrDictInfos {
        Id = i.Id,
        Keyword = i.Keyword,
        Description = administrationDbContext.ProcessWords(myText),
    };

var DataResult = (await Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync()).Description;
return DataResult;
```

---

To be honest, it's a rather strange thing to do: why select from the table if you are just discarding it?

If you just want to select the function value by itself then a straight `SqlQuery<string>` might be best.

```cs
var Dataresult = administrationDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(@$"
SELECT dbo.ProcessWords({myText});
");
```

Comment: I just I have ProcessWords function in sql server I want to access it i cant access it by using Description because I have already this column in my table

Comment: OK see edits...